# MATLAB slow to open files for editing

Tags: matlab

I'm on r2013a on Mac OS 10.8.3, and I'm noticing very slow performance when opening a .m file for editing. I ran the profiler on `open filename.m` and this is what I see:

[image: Profile information]

WHAT is it doing trying to read it as a video file? Couldn't it check the extension first? It's a `.m` file, why even bother checking if it's a video?

I'm interested to hear if there's a solution. The delay is getting on my nerves.

Comment: I have r2013a on a Win7 machine - it has the same problem. VideoReader gets invoked for opening a .cpp file too. Double clicking on the file is about 3 times as fast as using the open command, but it uses VideoReader too. The first time I opened a file it took 5.6s seconds with most of that time in VideoReader.init. Following that was much quicker mainly because VideoReader.init was much quicker.

Comment: Bizarre. I don't know of any movie formats with a `.m` extension -certainly not any that `VideoReader` supports. Sounds like possible abuse of `strncmp`. I don't see any any bug reports for this on the The MathWorks' site. You might [file one](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `edit filename.m` instead. It doesn't invoke VideoReader and is more than 10 times as fast.

Comment: That works, kind of. Any idea how to make it use that when double-clicking a .m file in the sidebar browser?

Comment: The culprit is the command finfo() which open calls. You could fix the behaviour of double clicking by editing uiopen.m (find it with which) and replacing `open(fn)` with `edit(fn)`. However this may lead to unwelcome surprises long after the change has been forgotten, so I am not going to do it. You may be more game than me.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that editing `finfo()` seems to solve the problem. If you do not have permissions to edit the original file, just place the modified copy somewhere and add it to MATLAB's path.

The modified `finfo()` has the following lines (starting at line 56 in the version I have). The only change is dealing with .m files is done prior and instead all the video/audio handling:

```
if ~isempty(ext)
    if any(strcmp(ext, {'m'}))
        % try to find handler on the path
        openAction = which(['open' ext]);
        loadAction = which([ext 'read']);
    else

        % Get the list of supported video file formats on this platform
        try
            videoFileFormats = VideoReader.getFileFormats;
            % extracting video file extensions
            videoFileExt = {videoFileFormats.Extension};
...
...
...
end %(line 134)
```

Now opening .m files either from the current folder panel or the command window `open()` works fast.